# On of @media queries gets skipped

Tags: css, media-queries

**EDIT** I have actually fixed the issue by recreating the bootstrap grid inside of the HTML, removing the need for the most media queries created. Thanks for all your help all!

I've run into a problem and can't seem to find the issue.

I have a project running on my web server, and all the media queries work except for one. It seems to skip over. It is shown in inspect element, I also validated the CSS which doesnt seem to find any errors, I also have the META Tag in my index.

The `@media screen and (max-width:1199px) {...}`  isn't working.

I hope you can help me get out of this problem, thanks!

Here's the CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1319px) {
  .release-title {
    margin-left:30px;
  }
  .release-desc {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .trend-ct .title {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .trend-ct .desc {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .newshoe-title {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .newshoe-desc {
    margin-left:30px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .geeks {
    height:600px;
  }

  .img-title {
    padding-top:5px;
  }

  .launch-title {
    margin-top:-10px;
  }
  .release-title {
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-top:10px;
  }

  .release-desc {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .trend-ct .title {
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .trend-ct .desc {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .trend-ct {
    height:480px;
  }

  .trend-ct .desc:hover {
    margin-left:60px;
  }

  .newshoe-title {
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .newshoe-desc {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .subbox {
    margin-top:-50px;
  }

  .footer {
    height:400px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1090px) {
  .geeks {
    height:100px;
  }

  .img-title {
    padding-top:5px;
  }

  .launch-title {
    margin-top:20px;
  }
  .release-title {
    margin-left:110px;
    margin-top:-100px;
  }

  .release-desc {
    margin-left:110px;
  }

  .trend-ct .title {
    margin-top:-110px;
    margin-left:110px;
  }

  .trend-ct .desc {
    margin-left:110px;
  }

  .trend-ct {
    height:800px;
  }

  .trend-ct .desc:hover {
    margin-left:165px;
  }

  .newshoe-title {
    margin-top:-110px;
    margin-left:110px;
  }

  .newshoe-desc {
    margin-left:110px;
  }

  .subbox {
    margin-top:-325px;
  }

  .footer {
    height:830px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 844px) {
  .between-ct {
    height:800px;
  }

  .subbox {
    margin-top:50px;
    float:left;
  }

  .nav-link{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    padding:20px;
    font-size:21px;
    font-weight:normal;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 813px) {
  .lookup {
    width:15%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 538px) {
  .lookup {
    width:20%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 445px) {
  .lookup {
    font-size:13px;
    top:-2px;
  }

  .subbox {
    width:100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 403px) {
  .between-ct {
    height:850px;
  }

  .lookup {
    width:25%;
  }
}
```

Here's my META Tag in the header:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: can you please put a sandbox/Fiddle/Snippet for your code?

Comment: are you able to see the media query in the debugger > style tab?

Comment: @Alphabetus Yes, it's seen in the debugger, but the 1099px width overrides it for some reason, even though the width is literally 1199PX

Comment: @Tawsif Its a complete site to be precise, I have a link to the project should you want to see it: https://travinity.com/projects/thjis/ Never had this problem before though

Comment: Who said it doesnt work?it works.the way you designed your media query,is a very,very ,very bad choice.

Comment: @tawsif I dont see any reference why it is bad designed. Please provide any if youre leaving comments like this. You should try and inspect element and go to 1199px width. It will show you that 1099px overides the 1199px, thats not bad designing, it means something is wrong with it. Thats the question. I hope you can add the critique to why it is bad designed instead of a feedback-less comment like this. Thanks

Comment: If i write new design of media queries, would it be ok?

Comment: @tawsif Yeah, if it will work, but I don't see the issue what coudl cause this, can you try to explain how my media query design could cause such an issue?

Comment: you only nedd 4 media queries to build a top-class premium website.i am giving you a link of such an example. [evaly.com.bd](http://evaly.com.bd).Shrink and expand the viewport to see how it behaves differently than yours.it's content doesn't get squeezed or re-aligned everytime screen-width is changed.this particular site has 4 media queries.

Comment: I usually use only about 3 media queries. However, the design of this website needs to change on certain pixels to fix some aligning issues. This is because its a combination of bootstrap grid alongside some content boxes that need a certain static width, creating some padding issues, which only occur between 1099 and 1199px, so theres 2 options, recreate the complete site or fix a 100 px width with just a media query. Nonetheless, it still should work and not be overridden by any lower media querys. Also, recreating the site would should add the same issue to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `only` after `@media`:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1319px) {
  .release-title {
    margin-left:30px;
  }
  .release-desc {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .trend-ct .title {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .trend-ct .desc {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .newshoe-title {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .newshoe-desc {
    margin-left:30px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .geeks {
    height:600px;
  }

  .img-title {
    padding-top:5px;
  }

  .launch-title {
    margin-top:-10px;
  }
  .release-title {
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-top:10px;
  }

  .release-desc {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .trend-ct .title {
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .trend-ct .desc {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .trend-ct {
    height:480px;
  }

  .trend-ct .desc:hover {
    margin-left:60px;
  }

  .newshoe-title {
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .newshoe-desc {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .subbox {
    margin-top:-50px;
  }

  .footer {
    height:400px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1090px) {
  .geeks {
    height:100px;
  }

  .img-title {
    padding-top:5px;
  }

  .launch-title {
    margin-top:20px;
  }
  .release-title {
    margin-left:110px;
    margin-top:-100px;
  }

  .release-desc {
    margin-left:110px;
  }

  .trend-ct .title {
    margin-top:-110px;
    margin-left:110px;
  }

  .trend-ct .desc {
    margin-left:110px;
  }

  .trend-ct {
    height:800px;
  }

  .trend-ct .desc:hover {
    margin-left:165px;
  }

  .newshoe-title {
    margin-top:-110px;
    margin-left:110px;
  }

  .newshoe-desc {
    margin-left:110px;
  }

  .subbox {
    margin-top:-325px;
  }

  .footer {
    height:830px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 844px) {
  .between-ct {
    height:800px;
  }

  .subbox {
    margin-top:50px;
    float:left;
  }

  .nav-link{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    padding:20px;
    font-size:21px;
    font-weight:normal;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 813px) {
  .lookup {
    width:15%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 538px) {
  .lookup {
    width:20%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 445px) {
  .lookup {
    font-size:13px;
    top:-2px;
  }

  .subbox {
    width:100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 403px) {
  .between-ct {
    height:850px;
  }

  .lookup {
    width:25%;
  }
}@media only screen and (max-width: 1319px) {
  .release-title {
    margin-left:30px;
  }
  .release-desc {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .trend-ct .title {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .trend-ct .desc {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .newshoe-title {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .newshoe-desc {
    margin-left:30px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .geeks {
    height:600px;
  }

  .img-title {
    padding-top:5px;
  }

  .launch-title {
    margin-top:-10px;
  }
  .release-title {
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-top:10px;
  }

  .release-desc {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .trend-ct .title {
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .trend-ct .desc {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .trend-ct {
    height:480px;
  }

  .trend-ct .desc:hover {
    margin-left:60px;
  }

  .newshoe-title {
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .newshoe-desc {
    margin-left:30px;
  }

  .subbox {
    margin-top:-50px;
  }

  .footer {
    height:400px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1090px) {
  .geeks {
    height:100px;
  }

  .img-title {
    padding-top:5px;
  }

  .launch-title {
    margin-top:20px;
  }
  .release-title {
    margin-left:110px;
    margin-top:-100px;
  }

  .release-desc {
    margin-left:110px;
  }

  .trend-ct .title {
    margin-top:-110px;
    margin-left:110px;
  }

  .trend-ct .desc {
    margin-left:110px;
  }

  .trend-ct {
    height:800px;
  }

  .trend-ct .desc:hover {
    margin-left:165px;
  }

  .newshoe-title {
    margin-top:-110px;
    margin-left:110px;
  }

  .newshoe-desc {
    margin-left:110px;
  }

  .subbox {
    margin-top:-325px;
  }

  .footer {
    height:830px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 844px) {
  .between-ct {
    height:800px;
  }

  .subbox {
    margin-top:50px;
    float:left;
  }

  .nav-link{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    padding:20px;
    font-size:21px;
    font-weight:normal;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 813px) {
  .lookup {
    width:15%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 538px) {
  .lookup {
    width:20%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 445px) {
  .lookup {
    font-size:13px;
    top:-2px;
  }

  .subbox {
    width:100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 403px) {
  .between-ct {
    height:850px;
  }

  .lookup {
    width:25%;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried the only screen and too, it didnt make it work either, and its only the media query for 1199 width px.